# Python Docx using literal '?' in regex within quotes

Tags: python, regex, python-re, python-docx

I am writing code using the Python docx library to find and highlight all quotes within the text. It works except if there is a question mark within the quote (e.g. it can find "How are you?" but returns NoneType object on "Hello? How are you?" and throws an AttributionError on `location.span()` below).

I tried fiddling around with the regex, including “([\w?]*?)” and \? into some tries, but nothing seems to work - my regex as below passes the regex checker with "Hello? How are you?" for example, but my program will not

```
document = Document(filepath)

def highlight_quotes(document):
    for paragraph in document.paragraphs:
        if matches := re.findall(r'“(.*?)”', paragraph.text):
            quotes = []
            for i in range(len(matches)):
                location = re.search(matches[i], paragraph.text)
                start_index, end_index = location.span()
                quotes.append((start_index, end_index))
```

Comment: Get out of the habit of using `for index in range(len(list)):`. Use `for item in list:` or `for index, item in enumerate(list):`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to use a portion of the text as a regular expression when you do `re.search(matches[i], paragraph.text)`. But it's not a regular expression, and if it contains characters that have special meaning in regular expressions (e.g. `?`) it will not match correctly, or may even raise an exception.

You could use `re.escape()` to escape all the special characters, but this still wouldn't be correct. If there are any duplicate matches, it will only return the position of the first one.

If you want to get the positions of the matches, use `re.finditer()` -- instead of returning the texts, it returns `match` objects, from which you can get the spans of each match.

```
def highlight_quotes(document):
    for paragraph in document.paragraphs:
        quotes = [match.span() for match in re.finditer(r'“(.*?)”', paragraph.text)]
        # rest of code
```

Comment: I wasn't even looking at the second re function - thank you! Yours is much more efficient

Comment: Isn't that where the error was occurring?

Comment: It was, but the code ran fine as ti was until it came across quotes that had question marks in the middle ('?' at the end was fine and code worked), so I originally assumed it was the first re match that was getting confused over the literal '?' in the quotes, and it was only flagging as a problem when I tried to span the match.